# How to get rows from 'list' table only. NOT PARENT TABLES

Tags: php, mysql

I want display rows from 'list' table only. But code below gives rows values from parent tables too

```
        mysqli_query($con, "select * from list
        RIGHT JOIN department ON list.department_id = department.id
        RIGHT JOIN subject ON list.subject_id = subject_id
        RIGHT JOIN sub_subject ON list.sub_subject_id = sub_subject_id
        order by list.id $order");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    mysqli_query($con, "select list.* from list
    Left JOIN department ON list.department_id = department.id
    Left JOIN subject ON list.subject_id = subject_id
    Left JOIN sub_subject ON list.sub_subject_id = sub_subject_id
Where department.id = NULL
And subject_id = NULL
And  sub_subject_id = NULL
order by list.id $order");
```

Comment: Sir, Its displaying rows from parent tables, which I don't want. Thank you

Comment: What's the name of the parent table?

Comment: department, subject ans sub_subject. list is table where I record most of data.

Comment: So really you want rows that don't join to any of these other tables, for example a list item where dept I'd doesn't exist in the dept table?